# Excel Formula to create two entries from one reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have all my data in Excel Column A and want to fill the Column B using Formula. See the attached Picture:

[image: example image]

If I use "&_x1" and "&_x2" with reference cell it is working but the limitation in this case is, I cannot drag it down to apply the same formula in the following cell in Column B. I have to manually adjust the reference cell by going to each and every rows in Column B.

Is there another approach I can use? My goal is, after I add the formula in Row1-ColumnB, if I drag the corner down, it should fill all the Rows of Column B. I don't need to adjust the formula in any other cell in Column B. The final table should look exactly like you see in the attached picture.

Answer (score 3):

The following formula will create the column you need.

Your description makes it clear you are populating a formal Table, so I did it in a manner that does not use `SPILL` functionality since that won't work in a Table.

```
=INDIRECT("A" & ROUNDUP(ROW()/2, 0)) & "_x" & IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1, 1, 2)
```

The source cell addressing is performed by using `INDIRECT()` on a string you create from the column letter and a formula. The formula takes the row number and divides by 2, then rounds UP. You divide by 2 to get pairs for each input. If you needed five items per set, you'd divide by 5, etc.

The "1" or "2" value needed in the "_x1" and "_x2" is gotten with another arithmetic operation, this time `MOD()` using 2 as the divisor and so getting either 1 (odd rows), or 0 (even rows). An `IF()` tests for which and gives the correct 1 or 2 for building that part of the string.

(If you were not using a Table and wanted `SPILL` functionality, you could do the same kinds of things using `SEQUENCE()` instead of `ROW()` to produce the numbers to be divided, or being trickier, you could use it to generate the row values directly.)

Comment: Thanks Jeorje! The ROW function works like a charm!

Could you also give an example with SEQUENCE function, if I want to control the reference row number? In case I want to start "AA_x1" from Row4, ColumnB.

Comment: If you have everything starting from row 4, then the `ROUNDUP(ROW()/2,0)` should be changed to `(3+ROUNDUP((ROW()-3)/2,0))` and `MOD(ROW(),2)` to `MOD((ROW()-3),2)`.

Comment: Awesome, that works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this:*

[image]

- An array (CSE) Formula in cell B42:

  `{=INDEX($A$42:$A$45, MATCH(FALSE, COUNTIF($B$41:B41, $A$42:$A$45)=2, 0))}`
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, and fill down till needed.
- **2** helps the formula in cell `B42` to repeat values from `A42:A45`, and is editable.
- Formula in cell C42:
  `=IF(COUNTIF(B$42:$B42,$B42)=1,B42&"_x1",IF(COUNTIF(B$42:$B42,$B42)=2,B42&"_x2",""))`
- Or you may use this also:
  `=IF(COUNTIF(B$42:$B42,$B42)=1,B42&"_x1",B42&"_x2")`

**N.B.**

- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*
- For neatness you may hide the Help Column.